# Ignore folder and its files from search results

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a special requirement where I have to use a **separate** command to filter out all **folders and their files** from the search result in Linux!

**Example:**
I have the following folders, and they all have a file called *test*

```
/testfolder/f1
/testfolder/f1_0VT0_hc1
/testfolder/f1_0VT0_hc2
```

So for example if I run `ls testfolder/*` the initial results would be:

```
/testfolder/f1:
test

/testfolder/f1_0VT0_hc1:
test

/testfolder/f1_0VT0_hc2:
test
```

I need to pipe in another command (e.g. `grep`) that would take in that result and filter out all directories that have the **_0VT0_** and their files!

I was able to ignore the directories using :

`ls testfolder/* | grep -R --exclude-from='.*_0VT0_.*'`

but I still got the files!

**Question:** how can I modify my grep command or what command should I use to ignore the folders and the files within them!

**Clarification** I will be given an `ls` or `find` command and I need **another** command to execute after them that will filter out such folders and their files. So something I can pipe or do in a batch file.

Comment: The `-R` and `--exclude-from` options to `grep` only makes sense when you give it directory names as arguments, not when it's reading from standard input.

Comment: @Barmar yes I came to realize that after running it so what other command/argument should I use?

Comment: Did you mean `grep -v` ?

Comment: @Thrustmaster `grep -v` would still give me the file names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-prune` option to `find`.

```
find * -name '*_0VT0_*' -prune -o -print
```

You can use this as part of another command with ordinary command substitution:

```
ls -d $(find * -name '*_0VT0_*' -prune -o -print)
```

Comment: would I be able to pipe this to the result of an `ls` or another `find` command?

Comment: You can use `find`'s `-ls` option to list the files instead of just printing filenames. You can use the `-exec` option to do things with the resulting files, or you can pipe the output to `xargs`, etc.

Comment: I am a noobie when it comes to shell scripting, your script gives me what I want. But it runs `find` separately and doesnt using the output of my `ls` when piped. As I said in my question I have a command that will execute and I cant change it, but I need to run another command on the first one results to ignore them. Is that possible